# Setting SQL Linked Server using DSN Connection

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008

We have Ctree Database ODBC Drivers which is installed and configured on our local system. We have DSN Connection which is ready to use.

Using DSN Connection, i need to establish SQL Linked Server Connection. I am very new to SQL Linked Server Connection settings. I am looking for more articles and help which could help me to establish SQL Linked Server Connection settings with DSN Connection.

Answer (score 0):

Use something like this (the name of the linked server will be CTREESRV):

```
USE [master]
GO
EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedserver @server = N'CTREESRV', @srvproduct=N'Ctree', @provider=N'MSDASQL', @datasrc=N'DSN_NAME_HERE', @location=N'SOMETHING', @provstr=N'DNS=DSN_NAME_HERE;UID=DSN_USRNAME_HERE;PWD=DSN_PASSWD_HERE', @catalog=N'DATABASENAME_HERE'

GO
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'CTREESRV', @optname=N'collation compatible', @optvalue=N'false'
GO
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'CTREESRV', @optname=N'data access', @optvalue=N'true'
GO
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'CTREESRV', @optname=N'dist', @optvalue=N'false'
GO
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'CTREESRV', @optname=N'pub', @optvalue=N'false'
GO
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'CTREESRV', @optname=N'rpc', @optvalue=N'false'
GO
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'CTREESRV', @optname=N'rpc out', @optvalue=N'false'
GO
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'CTREESRV', @optname=N'sub', @optvalue=N'false'
GO
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'CTREESRV', @optname=N'connect timeout', @optvalue=N'0'
GO
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'CTREESRV', @optname=N'collation name', @optvalue=null
GO
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'CTREESRV', @optname=N'lazy schema validation', @optvalue=N'false'
GO
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'CTREESRV', @optname=N'query timeout', @optvalue=N'0'
GO
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'CTREESRV', @optname=N'use remote collation', @optvalue=N'true'
GO
USE [master]
GO
EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedsrvlogin @rmtsrvname = N'CTREESRV', @locallogin = NULL , @useself = N'False'
GO
```

Comment: i am not able to understand, could you please share some sample link or with screenshot